# Save date as timestamp in CQ5

Tags: aem

I need t use the CQ5 xtype 'datefield' since I need only the date and not time tombe entered by the author.

But the issue is that 'datefield' saves the date in JCR as a String and not as a timestap [ as it does when 'datetime' is used.]

Is there a work around to save the date as a timestamp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough workaround for your jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.util.Date"%>

<%
SimpleDateFormat displayDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String dateField = properties.get("nameofdatefield", "");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(dateField);
String formattedDateStr = displayDateFormat.format(formattedDate);

out.println('Example of formated string'+formattedDateStr);
%>
```

From the above, you can also convert it to a Date Object, depending on what you wish to manipulate.

Let me know if the above example helps

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to save the date as timestamp using datefield, without meddling with the default script. But as a workaround, you can use **datetime** and set the property **hideTime** to true, to hide the time part, so that the author will not be able to author it.

The json for the config is shown below.

```
{   "fieldLabel":"Date",
    "xtype":"datetime",
    "hideTime":true,
    "name":"./date",
    "defaultValue":"now",
    "jcr:primaryType":"cq:Widget"
}
```

You can add **defaultValue** to **'now'**, if you  want current date to be initialized as the default, if not explicitly filled in by the author, else it can be ignored.

**NOTE**: The defaultValue: 'now' doesnt work for me in IE (i am using IE 11 and emulating the previous versions through dev tools), but it works fine in Chrome and Mozilla.